# nginx rule to append additional segment after the url

Tags: nginx

I have a dynamic URL's as follows

```
http://www.xxxx.com/black/xxxx/xxxx
http://www.xxxx.com/blue/xxxx/xxxx
http://www.xxxx.com/red/xxxx/xxxx
```

I want to do 301 redirect for the above url to

```
http://www.xxxx.com/color/black/xxxx/xxxx
http://www.xxxx.com/color/blue/xxxx/xxxx
http://www.xxxx.com/color/red/xxxx/xxxx
```

I'm trying the matching like this

```
location ~  /(black|blue|red)(/(.+)?)?$ {

}
```

Thanks in advcance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `location` regular expression should include an anchor for the beginning of the URI.

If you are trying to match only URIs containing the suffix `/xxxx/xxxx`, you can use the character class `[^/]` to match non-slash characters.

The redirect is straightforward using a `return` statement:

```
location ~ ^/(black|blue|red)/[^/]+/[^/]+$ {
    return 301 /color$request_uri;
}
```

The evaluation order of regular expression `location` blocks is significant. Place this block above other blocks with potentially conflicting rules.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.